# Matching a group with OR condition in pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the text between `<th>` tags from an HTML table. The following code explains the problem

```
searchstr = '<th class="c1">data 1</th><th>data 2</th>'
p = re.compile('<th\s+.*?>(.*?)</th>|<th>(.*?)</th>')
for i in p.finditer(searchstr):print i.group(1)
```

The output produced by the code is

```
data 1
None
```

If I change the pattern to `<th>(.*?)</th>|<th\s+.*?>(.*?)</th>` the output changes to

```
None
data 2
```

What is the correct way to catch the group in both cases.I am not using the pattern `<th.*?>(.*?)</th>` because there may be `<thead>` tags in the search string.

Comment: Don't [use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5827958).

Comment: just make it simple, `re.compile(r'<th\b[^>]*>(.*?)</th>')` . But it's better to follow ALex's answer.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I used that regex and it solved my problem(If you answer this, I can mark that as a solution). Alex's solution is much more elegant, and I would have used it but I didn't want to install a package for using it in just one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may reduce the regex like below with one capturing group.

```
re.compile(r'(?s)<th\b[^>]*>(.*?)</th>')
```

Answer (score 5):

[Why don't use an HTML Parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5827958) - [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), for example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> str = '<th class="c1">data 1</th><th>data 2</th>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(str, "html.parser")
>>> [th.get_text() for th in soup.find_all("th")]
[u'data 1', u'data 2']
```

Also note that `str` is a bad choice for a variable name - you are shadowing a [built-in `str`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: I would prefer not installing a package as there is just one instance where I need scraping, most of the work is done through APIs. I corrected the variable name, I had  put it in the example trying to simplify the post